# How to deserialize a list of objects with Json.net without knowing their types in advance?

Tags: json.net

I have a text file containing multiple lines of json, and each line represents one of several types. For example, the first line in the file might represent a serialized Foo, while the second line represents a serialized Bar, and so on.

The question is how to deserialize these lines? (Deserialization requires you to specify the Type to use, but I don't know in advance which Type each line represents)

At first I tried using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` on the serializer, which embeds a field name `$type` into the serialized json. This looked promising. I thought I could read each line in as a dynamic object, like this:

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(line_from_file);
```

and then extract out the `$type` field, and then use that to deserialize a concrete class, like this:

```
var concrete_object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(type indicated in $type)>(line_from_file);
```

But the `$type` field name doesn't seem to be accessible in the `o` object above returned from the dynamic deserialize.

I guess I could text-parse each line, looking for `$type`, but that seems messy too.

Comment: Please show an example of the JSON to be deserialized.  Do you control its format?  Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` when serializing is that you don't have to do any special processing to deserialize back to specific types.  As long as you also specify `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` when deserializing, the deserializer will read the embedded `$type` properties and instantiate/populate the correct object(s) for you.  (Note that [`DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) has non-generic overloads for this purpose which do *not* require specifying a Type parameter; perhaps that is the source of your confusion.)

Below is a round-trip demonstration program to illustrate the point.  It will create a couple of test objects, serialize them to a temporary JSON file as described in your question, then read the file back in, deserialize each line back to an object and dump out its type and contents to the console.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "foo" };
        Bar bar = new Bar { Length = 2.3, Width = 1.6 };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            Formatting = Formatting.None      // ensure no line breaks in the JSON
        };

        string fileName = @"C:\temp\Q37034748.json";

        // Write out sample file, one object per line
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings));
            sw.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bar, settings));
        }

        // Now read the file, deserializing each line to an object and dumping it out
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadLine(), settings);
                Dump(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Dump(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null) 
        {
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.GetValue(obj));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}

class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON file will look similar to this (your namespace/assembly name may be different):

```
{"$type":"JsonTest.Foo, JsonTest","Id":1,"Name":"foo"}
{"$type":"JsonTest.Bar, JsonTest","Length":2.3,"Width":1.6}
```

And the console output will look like this:

```
JsonTest.Foo
Id: 1
Name: foo

JsonTest.Bar
Length: 2.3
Width: 1.6
```